# How to convert an integer to byte literal in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am trying to convert an integer to byte literal in Rust:

```
for x in 0..10000 {
  let key = x.to_???;
  other_function(key);
}
```

Could not find it in the docs.

Comment: "byte literal" is not a type, you most likely mean `u8`. Also, how do you expect to convert `10000` to a byte?

Comment: I suspect you want to convert the integer to `&[u8]` or `[u8; n]` in either big endian or little endian byte order, but without further information it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `byte literal` is something like `b'f'`, a literal value written down. You probably mean a `byte`, which is usually a `u8`, sometimes an `i8`. You can use the `TryFrom`-trait on recent rust:

```
use std::convert::TryFrom;

fn main() {
    for i in 253..257 {
        let u = u8::try_from(i).expect("Not all integers can be represented via u8");
        println!("{}", u);
    }
}
```

`u` inside the loop is an `u8`. The code will print 253, 254, 255 and crash on the iteration where `i` becomes larger than what a `u8` can represent.

Comment: `'f'` is a _character literal_ and has type `char`. A byte literal would be `b'f'` of type 'u8'.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @SvenMarnach. This was not clear to me.